# Alternative to Gatling

Tags: java, scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I’ve been having issues lately because my dependencies has been updated to use netty 4.1 and Gatling has not been updated for a while, and still work only on Netty 4.0.

Anybody knows any alternative to Gatling to create similar Simulations and scenarios for the performance test to be run automatically in my Maven life cycle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look for something code-based it would be:

- [Locust](https://locust.io/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)

For UI and/or XML based scenario definition you can check out:

- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) (this one can be reliably run on Linux/Unix only)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Check out [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) to learn more about the aforementioned tools and decide which one fits to your most.

Answer (score 5):

As a nice replacement for Gatling I would recommend you to check the Locust. The good thing about the Locust specifically for you is that it is code based performance testing tool which does not enforce you to write the tests only in a specific programming language like Python. Because if you used Scala before, you might be more comfortable to switch to something like Java or even Kotlin while writing your tests which is more than doable using Locust framework. You can find the handy tutorial by this link:

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-performance-testing-using-java-and-kotlin

Comment: Looks interesting, and I´v been looking foward to touch Kotlin. Thank!

Answer (score 4):

Here's also a [benchmark comparison](http://blog.loadimpact.com/comparing-load-testing-tools) of different tools.

If you are javascript/Ecma familiar k6 does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Apache JMeter is a known alternative to Gatling.

It is frequently updated (at least 2 major releases per year) and has a strong user base and a lot of commercial offers.

There is a Maven Plugin that is being recently much more frequently updated, there has been 4 releases in 2 months.

Look at code coverage in more details.

Comment: Yes it’s possible run it in a Maven life cycle? I always used manually

Comment: Yes, JMeter Maven plugin is designed to do just that. https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin

Comment: 30% of code coverage? Mmm thanks but let’s see it there’s any other alternative

Comment: See https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/166 . Jmeter is frequently updated (at least 2 major releases per year) and has a strong user base and a lot of commercial offers.
This Maven Plugin  is being recently much more frequently updated, there has been 4 releases in 2 months.
Look at code coverage in more details.

Comment: yes but again it´s only has 35% of coverage. I cannot trust in a software with such a low overage code. Thanks anyway

Comment: There was a mis configuration leading to wrong coverage results. You can have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

k6 is a good alternative, if js is not a problem for you. https://k6.io/